# Как получить текст сообщения зная его id и chat_id (python aiogram)

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram, sendmessage

В документации телеграмма видел метод getMessages, который вроде как делает то что нужно. Но в aiogram такого не нашел. Может есть какой-то способ получить текст сообщения зная его id и chat_id

Answer (score 0):

get_chat_history()

Client.get_chat_history()

```
async for message in app.get_chat_history(chat_id):
    print(message.text)
```

https://docs.pyrogram.org/api/methods/get_chat_history

Comment: Спасибо за совет, как я понимаю ботом такое сделать нельзя, только увы клиентом

Comment: Я извиняюсь, невнимательно прочитал вопрос, и скинул метод для другой библиотеки(для pyrogram) для aiogram посмотрите types.message для работы с сообщениями